# Program crash on seemingly fine delete[]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, delete-operator

I'm using Visual C++ 2017 to build an OpenGL/GLFW application. However, I'm getting a crash on the `delete[]` statement with the message "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED : [...] CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer." in the following function I wrote :

```
#include <direct.h>

void setwd(char **argv)
{
    char *buf = new char[strlen(argv[0])];
    strcpy(buf, argv[0]);
    // Handle both possible separators
    char *p = strrchr(buf, '/');
    if(!p)
        p = strrchr(buf, '\\');
    if(p)
    {
        *(p + 1) = '\0';
        _chdir(buf);
    }
    delete[] buf;
}
```

If I delete my call to `setwd`, everything works fine. I made sure in debugging that `strlen(argv[0])` is never 0.

Worthy of note is that this works perfectly fine if compiled with MSYS2/gcc.

Comment: Off by one bug.  The buffer is too small  to hold the string.

Comment: Reduce your defect count and use `std::string` for text.  The `std::string` automatically manages memory for you, and has search and replace methods.

Comment: Don't do your own memory management. Leave this to the implementers of the low level structures. Use strings/vectors to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one extra character in the buffer, for the null terminator: `new char[strlen(argv[0])+1]`

Comment: Alright that works. Silly mistake, but why did it work fine on MSYS, and most of all, why did it wait until the `delete[]` operator to fail ? That's super misleading.

Comment: @Matrefeytontias it is undefined behavior, so exactly what will happen depends on the specific details of your implementation. In this case, your standard library's heap allocators are probably storing something useful after each block of memory returned from `new` (for example, the size of the allocation, or a pointer to the next one in some list of allocated objects), and you overwrote it. Then when the implementation tries to read this information, it gets confused. Using another toolchain, your new/delete implementations might work in a different way and have been fine.

Comment: Good enough for me. Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @Matrefeytontias I second others' recommendation to use `std::string` instead of raw char arrays. They are much easier to use correctly without causing bugs, mostly because they automatically manage their own memory without you having to worry about it.